# who kill my iperf on remote Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: server, iperf

I have a remote server with Ubuntu 14.04 and iperf 2.0.5. And also have a local device, which is use to test the throughput between local and remote server.
But a strange thing is sometimes the iperf progress on server been killed by unknow reason... The server is safe, so I believe it is automatic by the operation system or some other software. So my question is how to check who kill my iperf on server, and where can i check the log?

Comment: The remote server was used as a iperf client, data send by it. So maybe iperf been killed since it used to much bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the program crashes constantly. But to make sure you can check the logfiles. these are stored in `/var/log/nameoftheprogram.log`

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't find the /var/log/iperf.log on remote Server...

Comment: I googled it, was thinking but cannot find a possible log file. you can send a bug report to the developers.